Encountering logarithm of negative numbers, while solving a calculus problem.
I am tying to solve the following question:
Prove that the function given by f(x) = log(cos x) is strictly decreasing on $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$ and strictly increasing on $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right)$.
To solve this, first I calculated $f'(x) = -{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}$
I was able to show that f’(x) is negative in the interval $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2} \right)$. So f(x) is strictly decreasing.
Similarly, I was able to show that f'(x) is positive in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right)$. So f(x) must be strictly increasing.
But in the interval $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right)$, cosine is negative. So f(x) in this interval, is the logarithm of a negative number. Consequently, f(x) does not exist on $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi \right)$.
So I think, there is a mistake in the question. Could you please help to clarify this.

You're right. Congratulations for checking that your answer $f'(x) = -{\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}}$ makes no sense in the second interval.

@MasB Thank you very much. I felt something was not right, when I plotted f(x) and f'(x) on the same page. The f(x) is missing in the second interval.
